# on clicking image home page should be display?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
 </body>
  <div>
    <img class="floatLeftClass" id="float-Left-Class" src="images/logo.png" 
    width="100" height="50">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>   

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.floatLeftClass').click(function(){
            $(this).load( 'index.html' );
        });
    });
```

//this is image on clicking this index page should be displayed my script is

Comment: Is this code from a single file? If so put your javascript code in `<script>` and `</script>`

Comment: yes i am done with that but still not working

Comment: can you give us the file structure of your project?

Comment: You are calling `.load()` on the image, but it's supposed to be a container of some kind, usually a `<div>`. However why do this in the first place? Why not simply `<a href="index.html"><img ...></a>`?

Comment: i am using the script in the same page. with script tag

Comment: Why not just use a link? <a href="index.html"><img class="floatLeftClass" id="float-Left-Class" src="images/logo.png" 
    width="100" height="50"></a>

Comment: i have many pages that contain same img section.adding anchor to all file is time consuming. so i thought of adding script @chris G

Comment: Then it should probably be $('.floatLeftClass').click(function(){
            location.href =  'index.html';
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.floatLeftClass').click(function(){
    location.href = 'index.html'; 
});
```

The "load" function is something else - it loads the requested resource into an element (like a `<div>` or similar).

Edit: You can read the documentation of .load() here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try this Method ...

```
<div>
        <a href="https://www.w3.org/"> // Your page URL
            <img  id="img" src="imgname.png"  width="100" height="50">
        </a>
</div>
```